# QML layout does not have correct height

Tags: qt, qml

I have a qml layout and the ApplicationWindow does not stretch to the correct height for scrolling to work.

Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import "db.js" as DB

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: Screen.width
    title: "Nákupy"

    menuBar: MenuBar {

        Menu {
            title: "Smazat"
            MenuItem {
                text: "&Smazat seznam"
                onTriggered: {
                    console.log("Open action triggered");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentHeight: column.height
        contentWidth: root.width

        Column {
            anchors.fill: parent
            id: column

            Label {
                id: welcometext
                text: "Test"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                y: 10
                anchors.margins: 10
                width: root.width
            }

            Repeater {
                y: welcometext.top + welcometext.height + 10
                id: repeater
                model: lmodel
                Button {
                    id: b
                    text: m_text
                    x: 20
                    width: root.width - 40
                    height: 70
                    onClicked: {
                        visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            Button {
                y: repeater.top + repeater.height + 30
                width: root.width
                text: "Přidat položku"
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("clicked")
                }
            }

        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: lmodel
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        DB.open().transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, done INTEGER)");
        });
        console.log(column.height);
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            lmodel.append({m_text: "Test "+i});
        }
        console.log(column.height);
        console.log(welcometext.height);
    }

}
```

Column reports height 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`implicitHeight`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#implicitHeight-prop):

> Defines the natural width or height of the Item if no width or height is specified.
>
> The default implicit size for most items is 0x0, however some items have an inherent implicit size which cannot be overridden [...]
>
> Setting the implicit size is useful for defining components that have a preferred size based on their content [...]

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the `anchors.fill: parent` from child of the `Flickable`.
Instead, use explicit/implicit size of the children. In your case, the column calculates size of its' children automatically and so you don't need to set explicit size.

> Items declared as children of a Flickable are automatically parented to the Flickable's `contentItem`. This should be taken into account when operating on the children of the Flickable; it is usually the children of `contentItem` that are relevant. For example, the bound of Items added to the Flickable will be available by `contentItem.childrenRect`
> https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-flickable.html

Side note: the `contentWidth` property of the `Flickable` should be related to the content.